# Claim for Lost and then found baggage

Tags: air-travel, luggage, compensation, lost-luggage

I am in a tricky situation. In an emergency flight, a middle-eastern airline lost my one baggage. After 21 days as their policy- they asked me to submit the documents to claim it. They were supposed to reimburse me within next 21 days. That did not happen. Now they have found the baggage at a third airport, 1 month after filing the claim. I have not yet been contacted by them to collect it though, probably they are arranging it.

What should I do here? What and how I can claim? My baggage contained mostly edible items, which surely have rotted in this two-month period. Furthermore, to collect all this stuff its lots of efforts and time given being an annual trip to home.

Comment: I don't think most airlines allow perishable food items in checked luggage.

Comment: @hippietrail You've never brought homemade or unpackaged cookies or similar in your checked luggage? I have. Several times I've brought freshmade, preservative-free bread. That certainly wouldn't have lasted a week, let along over 21 days!

Comment: Only ever in my hand luggage other than alcohol before liquids were restricted. Certainly never "mostly edible items". But whether I've done it or not surely doesn't affect the airlines' rules about it or their willingness to compensate if I were to break that rule.

Answer (score 5):

If the airline found the bag AND you provided a specific delivery address when you filed the lost bag report, then they are responsible for delivering the bag to you at that address.

If the airline found the bag, but you did not specify a alternate delivery address (ie you were still traveling or such), then they are responsible for informing you (which sounds like may have happened).  Once informed that the bag has been found, you need to make arrangements with them for final delivery.

In both cases there is no law regarding how fast they have to get the bag to you, though usually it is simply a matter of putting a new bag tag and send it on its way.  Procedures on what customs might need to do when your bag arrives depend on the countries involved.

If the bag has been found and you have been duly notified, then you have no claim for lost items or time.  If you had to purchase essentials such as some clothes to wear or mandatory toiletries, then, if you can document costs (ie you have receipts), you can try to claim those costs.

Unfortunately, airlines do not accept liability claims for perishable items, those travel at your own risk, irregardless of the cause of any delay.

Comment: From your same reference: 8f) Fragile or perishable items must not be packed in baggage checked into the hold. You must not include in your checked baggage fragile or perishable items .... so including those items violates the terms, so the airline will not accept liability for illegally packed items.

Comment: It is not that computers are disallowed in the hold (as they do get shipped by air freight) it is that they are not allowed in your baggage in the hold.